# Dynamically shortened Text with "Show More" link according to the screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a long text that I want to show on different screen sizes.
The idea is: if the screen size is less then 320px I want the full text to be shortened with "Show More" link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var limit = 100;
        var chars = $("#myDiv").text();
        if (chars.length > limit) {
            var visiblePart = $("<span> " + chars.substr(0, limit - 1) + "</span>");
            var dots = $("<span class='dots'>... </span>");
            var hiddenPart = $("<span class='more'>" + chars.substr(limit - 1) + "</span>");
            var readMore = $("<span class='read-more'>Read More</span>");
            readMore.click(function () {
                $(this).prev().remove(); // remove dots
                $(this).next().show();
                $(this).remove(); // remove 'read more'
            });

            $("#myDiv").empty()
                .append(visiblePart)
                .append(dots)
                .append(readMore)
                .append(hiddenPart);
        }
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    span.read-more {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: red;
    }

    span.more {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Any idea what is the best way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take a tour of the help center to see how to ask a good question.  This site is mainly for if you have got stuck with a specific problem.  As it stands, your question is off topic as it is too broad and will have too many answers